# How to create custom completion block in Swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm trying to do some post processing

a. once one of my asynchrounous functions has finished

b. once all my asynchrounous functions have finished.

Unfortunately, I get into race conditions in my code below.

```
func foo(stuff: AnArrayOfObjects, completed: (NSError?)->()) {
    // STEP 1 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Create a dispatch group.
    let loadServiceGroup: dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create()

    // Define errors to be processed when everything is complete.
    // One error per service; in this example we'll have two
    let configError: NSError? = nil
    let preferenceError: NSError? = nil

    // some more preprocessing / variable declarations here. E.g.:
    var counter = 0

    // STEP 2 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Adding tasks to a dispatch group
    dispatch_group_enter(loadServiceGroup)

    // here i may start MULTPILE functions that are asynchronous. For example:
    for i in stuff {
       estore.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(remindersPredicate) {
            // MARK: Begininning of thread

            // does something here. E.g., count the elements:
            counter += 1

            // update the UI                    
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
               self.sendChangedNotification()        // reloads the tableview.
               // WARNING: I CAN'T JUST SHOW THE counter RESULTS HERE BECAUSE IT MIGHT NOT BE DONE YET. IT IS ASYNCHRONOUS, IT MIGHT STILL BE RUNNING.
            }
        }

        // STEP 3 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Leave dispatch group. This must be done at the end of the completion block.
        dispatch_group_leave(loadServiceGroup)

        // MARK: End of thread
    }

    // STEP 4 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Acting when the group is finished
    dispatch_group_notify(loadServiceGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // do something when asychrounous call block (above) has finished running. E.g.:
        print("number of elements: \(counter)")

        // Assess any errors
        var overallError: NSError? = nil;

        if configError != nil || preferenceError != nil {
            // Either make a new error or assign one of them to the overall error.
            overallError = configError ?? preferenceError
        }

        // Call the completed function passed to foo. This will contain additional stuff that I want executed in the end.
        completed(overallError)
    })   
}
```

Comment: You should add what you are _expecting_, and what you are actually experiencing. There's one potential data race: IFF statement `counter += 1` will be executed on different queues (more precisely, do not have the same parent queue), then it might be accessed on different threads, which is a data race in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't completely understand what you are doing. However, I always use a counter variable to determine whether all the async function finished or not.

```
func foo(completionHandler: (success: Bool) -> Void) {
    var numberOfTasks = 0
    for data in datasource {
        // do something preparing
        numberOfTasks += 1
    }

    var numberOfDones = 0
    objc_sync_enter(numberOfDones)
    data.foo(completionHandler:(){
        // do something handling outcome
        numberOfDones += 1
        if numberOfDones == numberOfTasks {
            completionHandler(true)
        }
    })
    objc_sync_exit(numberOfDones)
}
```

The mechanism is that we know the total number of tasks to be done, and for each task we can catch the completion event, consequently we added `numberOfDones`. Therefore, whenever `numberOfDones == numberOfTasks` we would know that this is the last one, and it has been done already.

Based on your code, I tried to apply this idea on it.

```
func foo(stuff: AnArrayOfObjects, completed: ([NSError]?)->()) {
    // STEP 1 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Create a dispatch group.
    let loadServiceGroup: dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create()

    // Define errors to be processed when everything is complete.
    // One error per service; in this example we'll have two
    let configError: NSError? = nil
    let preferenceError: NSError? = nil

    // some more preprocessing / variable declarations here. E.g.:
    var counter = 0

    // STEP 2 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Adding tasks to a dispatch group
    dispatch_group_enter(loadServiceGroup)

    // here i may start MULTPILE functions that are asynchronous. For example:
    for i in stuff {
        estore.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(remindersPredicate) {
            // MARK: Begininning of thread

            // does something here. E.g., count the elements:
            counter += 1

            // update the UI
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.sendChangedNotification()        // reloads the tableview.
                // WARNING: I CAN'T JUST SHOW THE counter RESULTS HERE BECAUSE IT MIGHT NOT BE DONE YET. IT IS ASYNCHRONOUS, IT MIGHT STILL BE RUNNING.
            }
        }

        // STEP 3 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Leave dispatch group. This must be done at the end of the completion block.
        dispatch_group_leave(loadServiceGroup)

        // MARK: End of thread
    }

    var numberOfDones = 0
    var errors = [NSError]()

    // STEP 4 OF CREATING AN OVERALL COMPLETION BLOCK: Acting when the group is finished
    objc_sync_enter(numberOfDones)
    dispatch_group_notify(loadServiceGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // do something when asychrounous call block (above) has finished running. E.g.:
        print("number of elements: \(counter)")

        // Assess any errors
        var overallError: NSError? = nil;

        if configError != nil || preferenceError != nil {
            // Either make a new error or assign one of them to the overall error.
            errors.append(configError ?? preferenceError!)
        }

        numberOfDones += 1
        if numberOfDones == counter {
            // Call the completed function passed to foo. This will contain additional stuff that I want executed in the end.
            completed(errors)
        }
    })
    objc_sync_exit(numberOfDones)
}
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @CouchDeveloper commented on my answer. I work out another solution which makes thread safe by synchronising the counter variable. The answer is updated and below is an experiment of the solution

https://gist.github.com/qiuyujx/7173ea663308cc03f07e8a5c09cf4cba

Comment: Unfortunately, your first code snippet has a potential data race, which is exactly what the OP tried to avoid. You _can_ use a variable to count the number of invocations, if the access to variable `count` is synchronised. For example, let all accesses execute on a serial dispatch queue. Since the "execution context" of the completion handler is not known - this first code sample bears a risk and should be avoided. As a consequence, your subsequent solution is incorrect as well.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thanks for commenting. I still don't understand why my idea is risky. Please see my edit which is a proof of my theory. Since I've used this idea into several of my projects, please correct me and it will be extremely appreciated if I'm wrong. So far there are no bugs related reported, but thread safety can be serious problem. Thanks a lot if you could correct me.

Comment: A data race occurs, if two or more threads access a shared variable without synchronisation where at least one access is a write. I put a code snippet on gist https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/ca040feec33ab5026ff2 which demonstrates the data race.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thanks very much for your example. Now I have better understanding of "data race". Based on its definition, I work out a solution by synchronising the counter variable. Do you think this solution actually solved this problem perfectly? Here is my folk https://gist.github.com/qiuyujx/7173ea663308cc03f07e8a5c09cf4cba

Comment: While `objc_sync_enter` is basically a mutex and can be used to synchronise access to a shared variable, it's not the way you should synchronise it in this case. If you look at my example, simply use the other queue, which is a serial queue (instead of the concurrent queue), and which is commented out.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Apparently, your solution is more appropriate and make more sense to this question. However, there are 3 reasons for me to post this answer. Firstly, I think it is not that good to post answers that worked out by someone else, so you may simply post it by yourself if you want. Secondly, my answer is the best solution for myself in my existing projects, since it does not require to modify too much, just add 2 lines. Also, it should be able to meet op's requirement anyway...